# File name extension to MIME type

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, mime-types

Using only JavaScript and framework like dojo/jQuery...

Is there a way to find the Content-Type for a particular file name extension?

Say if I type in the string "something.pdf", I want to show an alert that says "application/pdf"

or "something.html" show "text/html"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you will need to maintain the mappings yourself (you *could* XHR a physical file and get it, but I doubt you want to do that)...

```
(function() {

    var extToMimes = {
       'img': 'image/jpeg',
       'png': 'image/png',
       ...
    }

    window.getMimeByExt = function(ext) {
        if (extToMimes.hasOwnProperty(ext)) {
           return extToMimes[ext];
        }
        return false;
    }

})();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/avZJF/).

This will return `false` if it doesn't exist in your mapping. If you like, you could just return the `extToMimes[ext]`, which will give `undefined` if it doesn't exist. It also [won't accidentally get things up the prototype chain](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/72RAL/).

There is also the option of accessing it if it is a file `input`.

```
var mime = $('input[type="file"]').prop('files')[0].file;
```

Keep in mind the extension to mime type makes no guarantees about the actual file itself; you'd need to parse it server side to determine what kind of file it really is.

Comment: Just wondering if this answer is still correct seeing as it's 4 years old? Would we still need to maintain the mapping ourselves?

Comment: @Marklar If you don't have a file to upload, but simply an extension, I think you need a mapping. However, seems someone is maintaining one [here](https://github.com/rsdoiel/mimetype-js).

Comment: what if you do have a file to upload? Do you use XHR?

Comment: @Marklar If the user has chosen a file, you can get the mime type out using  JavaScript as demonstrated in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

you can use [node-mime](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime)

```
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/mime@latest"></script>
<script>
    mime.getType("something.pdf"); // etc.
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://wzrd.in/standalone/mime@latest is currently not available, so you have to use:

```
<script>
   import mime  from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/mime';
   console.log(  mime.getType("file.jpg"));
</script>
```